# Exchange 2003 purge old attachments from mailboxes

Tags: exchange, attachment

i have to save space in my server and i thought to purge the old attachments of email, is it possibile with exchange 2003? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of different ways you can save space on Exchange 2003. [Here](http://www.ehow.com/how_5988691_do-exchange-2003-mailbox-store_.html) is a good article which explains a couple ways.

There is also a program with Exchange 2003 that comes with the Exchange Resource Kit called EXMERGE that can be used to remove and delete objects within your mailbox folders.

Comment: While Exmerge certainly can be used to archive email and attachments out of the Exchange mailbox store, the physical file will remain the same size. In order to reclaim the free space from the physical file an offline defrag of the mailbox store needs to be performed with eseutil.

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot purge attachments separately using native Exchange tools.